# How can I handle events from MS Word spell checker using MFC?

Tags: c++, events, mfc, ms-word, spell-checking

I am working on a spell checker implementation in my application (unmanaged C++) using Visual C++ 6.0. I am able to access MS Word and open it using MFC. For spell checking, I am calling the function:

```
doc.CheckSpelling(mLocation,m_vOpt,m_vOpt, m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt,m_vOpt);
```

where doc is the object of `_Document` got from `_application.GetDocuments()`.

This will open up the MS Word spell checking pop-up window with suggested words.

Now, I want to handle the event created by clicking the "Change all" or "Ignore all" buttons present in the spell checking pop-up window of the Word application.

Can anyone tell me the procedure to implement handling of these events from MS Word? I tried searching for event handling for MS Word, however all the solutions are in .NET. I would like to know how to do this using MFC in C++ application.

Comment: Is there actually an "event created by clicking the "Change all" or "Ignore all" buttons"? (I can't find one documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297933(v=office.11).aspx.) I think you may be asking how to handle something that doesn't exist. (If it does exist, a pointer to the documentation would be helpful.) There are techniques to subclass window procedures to intercept mouse clicks on Win32 buttons, but that's more complex than handling a documented COM event in C++/MFC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't react to these buttons, as they come from Word directly. But you can get a list with spelling suggestions. All you have to do is to create a dialog with the buttons yourself.

Look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153842/access-ms-word-spell-checker-from-unmanaged-c/2153869#2153869).

Comment: Thank you Bradley and dwo for your suggestions.